# Is a dryer at risk of overheating on a hot day?

Tags: safety, dryer

Say around 32 C or 90 F, inside, not in the sun, near an open door. Is there a risk a dryer will overheat? Or does it regulate temperature so it'll just not heat as much use less energy to run (with hot days being no more risky than cold ones)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, there shouldn't be a problem.**

I'm an appliance service technician.

All of the electric dryers that I've seen use a form of electronic thermostat to keep the drum temperature below its operation temperature limit.
Often they use two or three at different locations. One of them may require a manual reset, assuring that the user knows that it tripped, to warn of blocked vent for example.

This being the case, there should be no additional danger because of high outside temperature. If the temperature would by some freak be over the design temperature of the machine, it just wouldn't turn on.

**Edit:**

Because of several (admittedly well-placed) comments, I am adding a picture of a typical dryer thermostat. Usually they are normal closed, opening at their specified limit somewhere between 65 and 180° C (150-360°F). For reference, the limit for long-term (more than half a day) human survival is [supposed](https://interestingengineering.com/science/how-much-heat-can-humans-survive-scientists-reveal) to be at approximately a 35°C (95°F) wet-bulb temperature.[image: dryer thermostat with manual reset]

Comment: 45-50C is hot enough to be deadly, but there's no way a dryer is that "cool".

Comment: I guess the key point is that a dryer heats until it reaches its proper operating temperature. If it starts out at 40°C ambient temperature it will reach that point much quicker than if it starts out at 5°C ambient temperature.

Comment: @Nelson the low mode is supposed to be 50--55°C depending on the manufacturer.  And it's all about time at temperature, for people.  Saunas are typically around 80°C but most people don't spend more than 10 minutes in them at a time